# Can you create an exploded .war in Intellij without having the ultimate edition

Tags: testing, weblogic, war, intellij-13

I'm trying to hot deploy a .war file to a Weblogic container so that I don't have to do a full build and then drag and drop the .war to the autodeploy folder each time I want to test my changes.

So far I've found that on the weblogic side of this it's easy, I just have to add the  tags to mark it to be watched. It just has to be an exploded .war

As far as I can tell so far IntelliJ can't give out exploded .war's unless it is the Ultimate edition.

Is there actually a way to get these exploded .war files? Or is there another way that someone can suggest for me to do this.

Thanks.